# typescript this cannot be referenced inside a module body

Tags: typescript

I have a module like

```
module nganimaltracker {
   export class TrayController implements ITrayController{
        public startTracker() {
        var monitor = new animalPositionMonitor(this);
        this.animalTrackerServices.TrackPosition(monitor,  this.errorCallbackFn);
    }
   }
}
var animalPositionMonitor: any = (() => {
    var jsClass: any = (trayController: ITrayController) => {
        **var monitor =  this;**
         var me: IGenXStreamHandler<IAnimal> = new GenXStreamHandler('Animal');
        me.process = animal => {
            var ll = **monitor["trayController"].gridOptions.data.length**;
        }
    }
}
```

If i don't have module it works. But I need to keep the module, also I need the monitor["trayController"] to access the element on a process call back so i won't lose scope. how do i do this?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code to the Typescript playground on their site and it compiled fine. What errors do you get, and on what lines? What version of TS?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `new animalPositionMonitor(this);` you should refactor `animalPositionMonitor` into a `class` as you are calling it with `new`.

Going furhter into your code you are adding stuff to `me` of type stream handler. To pass in `this` into that you would use a lambda, no need to capture `this` in a variable `monitor`.

```
class animalPositionMonitor{
    constructor(trayContrller:ITrayController){
        var me: IGenXStreamHandler<IAnimal> = new GenXStreamHandler('Animal');
        me.process = animal => {
            var ll = this["trayController"].gridOptions.data.length**;
        }   
    }
}
```

This quick video should help you understand `this` better : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA